# Leaflet map with 'query of features' on mouseover and multiple layers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, layers, web-mapping, query

I have produced two working Leaflet maps that in total contain the features that I need for my application. However, I cannot solve how to have multiple 'overlay' layers that can be queried with mouseover.

This map has the query features and display data feature that I want:

[Map with polygon query](https://github.com/trosendal/CWD_map/blob/203bb4e45653fb84c1a6e13be6a46cfc17f2e3e0/map.html)

This map has the multiple layers and multiple legends that I want:

[Map with multiple layers](https://github.com/trosendal/CWD_map/blob/203bb4e45653fb84c1a6e13be6a46cfc17f2e3e0/test/map.html)

When I try to implement the 'query and return data' in the 'multiple layers' map I think I am failing to properly understand the way the data structure has changed when the data is part of a layer instead of just in the map object.

Any ideas on how I can make this work? Feel free to make a pull request to my github repo if you want.